# How to extract all text from pdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I'm using the PYPDF2 lib to extract texts from a PDF but I'm having a problem doing the loop.

I'm using the following code and I can extract a string from the first page.

> ```
> from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
> reader = PdfFileReader("mypdf.pdf")
> # Print number of pages
> num_page = reader.getNumPages()
> print(num_page)
> # Print the number of pages where [0] is the first page
> page = reader.pages[0]
> print(page.extractText())
> ```

I would like to use the page number that I get with `.GetNumPages()` and iterate the number of times over `reader.pages[0]`

Code that I'm trying to print the 99 pages:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader reader = PdfFileReader("mypdf.pdf")
# Print number of pages num_page = reader.getNumPages() print(num_page)
# Print the number of pages where [0] is the first page

page = reader.pages[0] i = 0 print(type(num_page)) print(type(i)) for i in page:
    if i < num_page:
        page = reader.pages[i]
        print(page.extractText())
        i = i + 1
    else:
        print("done")
```

Error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wilian/PycharmProjects/ExtractText/pypdf.py", line 13, in <module>
    if i < num_page:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NameObject' and 'int'
99
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: why not use `for i in range(num_page)` then `page = reader.pages[i]`

Comment: Or `for page in reader.pages: page.extractText()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try simple for range loop*

*Example*

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


def pdf_info():
    with open("my_pdf.pdf", "rb") as f:
        reader = PdfFileReader(f)
        for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
            print(i)
            # page = reader.pages[i]
            # print(page.extractText())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_info()
```